# charAt().equals() causes "char cannot be dereferenced"

Tags: java

I am trying to check a string for hyphens at different positions (for a phone number because the input varies), but I keep getting the error

> char cannot be dereferenced

Code:

```
do {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter String");
    String raw = br.readLine();

    if (raw.length() < 10) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please input a valid phone number of at least 10 digits/letters");
        System.out.println("");
    } else {
        if (raw.charAt(3).equals('-') && raw.charAt(7).equals('-')) {
            System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 7");
        } else if (raw.charAt(3).equals('-')
                && raw.charAt(8).equals('-')) {
            System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 8");
        } else if (raw.charAt(3).equals('-')
                && raw.charAt(9).equals('-')) {
            System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 9");
        }
    }
} while (1 < 2);
```

Comment: What does `String#charAt()` method returns?

Comment: `char` is a primitive type. It has no methods. But you can compare chars with `==`

Comment: Why are you not using regex?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use something like this, it will work:

```
  if (raw.charAt(3) == '-' && raw.charAt(7) == '-') {

      System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 7");

  } else if (raw.charAt(3) == '-' && raw.charAt(8) == '-') {

      System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 8");

  } else if (raw.charAt(3) == '-' && raw.charAt(9) == '-') {

      System.out.println("2 Hyphens at 3 and 9");

  }
```

The problem is that `raw.charAt(n)` returns a `char` and not a `String`. The `equals()` method can be used only on objects. Char is a [primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which has no methods. On chars you should use operators like `==` or `!=`.

Comment: All objects have an `equals()` method, not just `String`s.

Comment: I was walking about Strings and chars. I will edit my answer to be more precise.